# Databricks Log Analytics Logs missing log

Tags: databricks, azure-log-analytics

I'm retrieving Log Analytics databricks logs in Databricks. The logs are looking like this:

```
{
  "notebookId": "462939155748830",
  "clusterId": "1222-165905-y1sn2ifz",
  "executionTime": "0.787",
  "status": "failed",
  "commandLanguage": "python",
  "commandId": "2234280281766336",
  "commandText":"import requests  \n  \n# Azure AD authentication credentials  \nclient_id = \"c1a74ac8-13fd-4bc4-9e0e-abd0bbdfe499\"
```

For the other environment the log commandText is missing, how can i retrieve this log, is it some kind of configuration or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i retrieve this log, is it some kind of configuration or something else?

I have got the logs of that when I enabled verbose audit logs . Click on Admin settings then on advanced and the enable like below:

[image]

and when i executed the cell :

[image]

I have got logs:

[image]